# how to create file in java in resources directory

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project and need to write JSON objects in file.json that should be located in

src/main/resources/

But before I need to check if file exists. If not than create it.

```
public static void writeMenuJSon(String jsonParamIn) {
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject modulJson = parser.parse(jsonParamIn).getAsJsonObject();

    //TODO check if file exists and create file if not

   code here ...


   // write to file JSON object
   try (Writer writer = new FileWriter("path to file")){

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        gson.toJson(modulJson, writer);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Usually, the `resources` folder should contain only resources from your project, and not dynamically created files. Why do you need a file there?

Comment: Writing into `src/main/resources` does not make sense cause this will be packaged later into the resulting jar file ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something is totally wrong if you are creating dynamically file in `src/main/resources` This is only going to work in your development environment. When you deploy your code using Jar or War there won't be this directory on file system. It will be contained within Jar / War or other packaging.

If you understand above and still want to do it. Go related to your current working directory to create file, Usually the working directory when you launch your Main from IDE is setup to root of project so create a file at

`src/main/resources/foo.txt`

will do it. Alternatively you can figure out your current working directory from your IDE launcher or at runtime using

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

Comment: Yes, it will be packaged in war file and deploy on glassfish. So where should I save this file? In WEB-INF directory?

Comment: You should create a workspace for application and that should live external to your application deployment. Also if you application allows user input to select file path, be sure you think with security aspect as well

Comment: If I understand you correctly you mean that all files cannot be changed after packaging in war file and deploying on the server or it is a bad practise. Right? But I need to make changes in this file when project is deployed and up and running. Should I put this file somewhere on the same server where this application is running? What is the best practice? Sorry if my questions is a lit bit stupid.

Comment: You can write file anywhere you like as long as you have permission. It is usually expected that application can get deployed/undeployed so your data will no longer be there also it is not cleaner way of doing it. So store to external to the application's deployed directory. for example `/home/someuser/applicationFoo/workspace/`

Answer (score 1):

What are you exactly trying to achieve writing the JSON file to the mentioned directory ?

I might miss something important in your question but:

it is possible to create code that does this thing but i'm not sure at all how are you going to run this code and is it sane solution to your problem?

When you mvn package the project name P having this "src/main/resources/" resources there will be added to package P.war/.jar or so but there will not be any JSON-file in directory until you run the code - this code you are after - that generates it and it is not done without some -maybe ugly- extra job.

If you have this code included in this project it will be run only when the project package is run. And there will not be this "src/main/resources/" where to write it.

Comment: I think you are right. The goal is to save links other modules menu from  in json file. It should be automatically generated when new module is deploying on server. On of possible solutions is to store this menu in JSON file. I thought it should be in src/main/resources directory. But probably it should be store somewhere else. For example in WEB-INF. What do you think about it?

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean with 'module' and deploying modules ? For example: do you have one 'main' application that will have links to other apps deployed to same application server/servlet container or so ?

Comment: There is a main module that create and managed menu. This menu should be dynamically created when new sub module is deploying  than links should creates in menu. One way to implement in to store menu in example_menu.json file and basic module can get links from it. All modules run on the same application server.

Comment: Maybe your main app could generate menu by listing sub directories under '${app.server.home}/webapps' so no need to maintain any json file ?